# XNA and Linq on Xbox360

Tags: c#, linq, xna

Please excuse the newbie question but I was wondering if I used Linq in my XNA application, would this still work on the Xbox 360?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes the Xna framework for *Xbox 360* and *Zune* **supports LINQ**.

(Look in `System.Core.dll` in `$PROGRAM_FILES$\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v3.1\References\Xbox360`)

Answer (score 4):

Yes it will work, but you should be aware that normal use of LINQ queries involves using lambdas which will generate gargabe pretty fast if you run your queries a lot. This means you could have issues in the Xbox360 as the GC is pretty simple there.